# Network timeouts in Android

Tags: android

I am experiencing way too many timeouts in the communication between my app and my server..
My problem is that the server doesn't even get the message. So I guess the problem is somewhere inside my Android code and not the server code.

Here is my code:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

    //configure timeouts
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 1000 * 1000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 1000 * 1000);

    //and finally initialize the http client
    this.mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(manager,params);

    //init the response handler
    this.mResponseHandler = new MyResponseHandler(ctx);




    final HttpPost method = new HttpPost(HttpSender.SERVER_URL);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", s));

    try {
        method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Runnable sender = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mClient.execute(method, mResponseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                Log.v(TAG, "unable to send " + s);
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.v(TAG, "unable to send " + s);
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(sender).start();
```

Is there something wrong with my code? By the way it doesn't always timeout.. just about 2/3 of the time

EDIT : I noticed that when i start the phone it usually works fine (no timeouts) but after
a few messages i start getting the timeouts so maybe i am not closing something correctly
in my code?

EDIT : another thing i have noticed is that if the messages work fine and then i turn my phone (from vertical to horizontal and vice versa)
the problems arise again and right after the orientation change i get:

```
10-03 11:47:46.920: ERROR/[FT]-Server(3563): NetworkStateReceiver :intent: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

Thanks for your help!
Omri

Comment: Do you use WiFi or mobile network? Maybe a bad connection so your code is right but the connection just fails? (only a guess)

Comment: using network connection but i am able to load sites in my browser with no particular problem (tried wifi too and it causes problems as well) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i am not exactly sure what solved it but i think the problem was that i wasn't closing
connection and methods anyhow here is my code if any one is interested:

```
public class HttpSender {

private ResponseHandler<String> mResponseHandler;
private String TAG = "HttpSender";
static final String SERVER_URL = "http://**some ip address**/myServer";

public HttpSender(Context ctx){
    //init the response handler
    this.mResponseHandler = new MyResponseHandler(ctx);
}

//TODO : see if using postSend is better and dosent cause timeouts?
public void send(final String s,final Context ctx, final int type){
    Log.v(TAG, "sending message : " + s + "type message of is " + Integer.toString(type));

    //for testing
    Toast.makeText(ctx,"sending \n" + s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //done for testing

    this.postSend(s, ctx, type);


}


public void postSend(final String s,final Context ctx,final int type){
    final HttpPost method = new HttpPost(HttpSender.SERVER_URL);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", s));

    final DefaultHttpClient client = getNewClient(ctx);

    try {
        method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Runnable sender = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                client.execute(method, mResponseHandler, new BasicHttpContext());
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                method.abort(); 
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                method.abort();

                Log.v(TAG, "unable to send " + s);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(sender).start();

}



private DefaultHttpClient getNewClient(Context ctx) {

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

    //and finally initialize the http client
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(manager,params);

    return client;
}
```

Comment: I started having this problem too, thanks for the suggestion. I've closed my connections it seems to be a little more stable.